# API authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, security, authorization

Please forgive me if this question has been asked/answered somewhere else. I've been researching for a while and I haven't found a good answer yet.

I have an API that needs to serve (at least) two different types of consumers with different needs and privileges. I'm of course talking about the concept of authorization, which is certainly well-worn territory within web apps. But, strangely, googling "api authorization" or "api acl" doesn't bring up anything that I find all that meaningful.

So my question is: **how do you properly handle authorization (not authentication) when writing an API?**

I would think that this answer could be answered in a technology-agnostic way, but if it helps, I'm using Rails.

Comment: I've tagged your question with Rails since `API`s will be dependent on the language.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted and voted to close, but feel free to explain why. Seems like a perfectly valid and constructive question to me.

Comment: This question is pretty much the definition of not constructive. "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. "

Comment: +1 since it seems constructive to me. The man is simply asking for any existing APIs on authorization that can be used in Rails. How is that open for debate?

Comment: You can use [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) gem in combination with [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem